# Sorting by the average score Python

Tags: python, file, sorting

So my program currently sorts by name and by score but I need to create an average score for the user.

Here is a quick sample of my file:

```
Reece 5  
John 6  
Reece 8  
Reece 9  
Alex 9
```

I need to be able to print the average score for Reece like so:

```
Reece 7.3
```

7.3 being the average of 5,8,9

I am not completely sure how to control this, any help?

Comment: not sure how are you getting your input but [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a file `file.txt` that you're reading, you can work out the average of a persons score by:

```
def getMean(name):
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
        total = 0
        count = 0
        for line in f.readlines():
            line = line.split(" ")
            if line[0] == name:
                total += int(line[1])
                count += 1
        return total/count
```

This reads every line in a file, splits it on the space, and whenever the first word equals the name that you are looking for, it adds the value to a running total and increments a count.  Then, at the end, it can work out the mean.  An example call would be:

```
>>> getMean("Reece")
7.333333333333
```

If you want to round that to one decimal place, you have two options, the first would be to round the return value:

```
>>> round(getMean("Reece"), 1)
7.3
```

Or round it in the function:

```
return round(total/count,1)
```

Comment: When I use this for the first time and the user gets a score of 0 you get a zero division error

Comment: @rward37 Aha!  That would be the case of course.  You can catch that out with a simple `try: except:` statement.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the information into some sort of data structure (for example, a dictionary). 
   This means you'll have to parse the data as you read it, meaning, that while you're reading the data you'll need to be able understand which part is the key (in this case the name) and which part is the value (meaning the score)
2. Compute an average score for every person, this will vary according to the way you choose to store your data.
3. Sort using the computed information.

Answer (score 0):

One way one could do it is to read the values into a dictionary of lists(using python3).

```
mydic={}
with open('myfile.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        name,value=line.split()
        value=int(value)#or float
        if name in mydic.keys():
           mydic[name].append(value)
        else:
            mydic[name]=[value]
#compute average:
for name in mydic:
    average=sum(mydic[name])/len(mydic[name])
    print("{} : {}".format(name,average))
```

Which gives the output:

```
John : 6.0
Alex : 9.0
Reece : 7.333333333333333
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
def get_average(data):
    vals = {item.split()[0]: [] for item in data.splitlines()}
    for item in data.splitlines():
        vals[item.split()[0]].append(float(item.split()[1]))
    return { k: sum(v) / len(v) for k, v in vals.iteritems()}


data = '''Reece 5  
John 6  
Reece 8  
Reece 9  
Alex 9  '''

average = get_average(data)
print(average['Reece'])
```

Output

```
7.33333333333
```